# Equivalent to the structure in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

What is a C#-equivalent to the following structure from C:

```
struct  netbuf{
unsigned int    maxlen;
unsigned int    len;
char            *buf;
};
```

I have translated it as:

```
public struct netbuf
{
    public uint maxlen;
    public uint len;
    public string buf;
};
```

but it seems to not be correct.

I have a legacy c code:

```
datagramm.addr.maxlen   = 0;
datagramm.addr.len      = 0;
datagramm.addr.buf      = (char*) 0;
datagramm.opt.maxlen    = 0;
datagramm.opt.len       = 0;
datagramm.opt.buf       = (char*) 0;

datagramm.udata.len   = sizeof(xliconf);
datagramm.udata.buf   = (char*)&xliconf;

xliconf.ccb_h.source = (uint8)ctrl_ed;
rval = xli_sndudata(ctrl_ed,&datagramm);
```

where declaration of xli_sndudata from header:

```
int xli_sndudata( int , struct t_unitdata *);
```

and

```
struct t_unitdata{
    struct netbuf   addr;     
    struct netbuf   opt;  
    struct netbuf   udata;   
};
```

Struct netbuf is above. I need to translate that code in C#.

Comment: Why does it seem to be not correct?

Comment: I'm no expert in C, but why shouldn't `buf`be a `char` in C# as well?

Comment: @SomeBody An instance of it is used as a parameter by a function from the library. I have the legacy C code and can compare the values. I fill the structure with the same values, but the function returns error

Comment: @smok buf isn't char  in the C code. Look closely.

Comment: In order for us to answer we need to know how the struct is used. There is no single one size fits all translation.

Comment: Unmanaged structures aren't specific enough to be translated on their own. You need to share the documentation, or the way the structures are used. Who creates and frees the buffer? How is the struct passed between caller and callee? It looks like this is essentially meant to be a `byte[]` (or really, `Span<byte>`), but that's just guessing. Unmanaged code leaves a lot more questions open than managed code - you need to answer those before we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *Edited*: `uint` is correct
- `char*` can be `IntPtr` or `byte*` (requires `unsafe`)
- Don't forget `StructLayout` - otherwise [CLR might add arbitrary padding or change the order of the fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public struct netbuf
{
    public ushort maxlen;
    public ushort len;
    public IntPtr buf;
};
```

Comment: Structs have `Sequential` by default, and you probably don't want to use `Pack = 0`, unless that's how the structure is defined on the unmanaged side too.

Comment: No, `int` in C platforms which have pinvoke is 4 bytes. And the pack setting looks wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan source?

Comment: Source? Me, here, now.

Comment: I also thought that should rather be `byte[]`. But is it `char` not a `sbyte` in C#?

Comment: @kyy If you want useful help, please address the comments below your question

Comment: @kyy8080 C# chars are 16bit wide, so akin to ushort.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine. Though the struct is not a class, the syntax is very close, with a few restrictions as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct

> Structs can also contain constructors, constants, fields, methods, properties, indexers, operators, events, and nested types, although if several such members are required, you should consider making your type a class instead.
>
> Structs can implement an interface but they cannot inherit from another struct. For that reason, struct members cannot be declared as protected.

The official example is very similar to what you have there.

Comment: Probably this struct is used to return a string. So the translation into C# is wrong.

Comment: Seems like it's used as a network buffer, not just a string. (From the struct name)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A byte array, more likely. It's the hoops you need to go through to return `byte[]` in C :) And it seems that either the caller might be responsible for freeing the memory (ouch), or the struct is used both ways - the caller passes buf and maxlength, and the callee returns data in the buffer and actual length.

Comment: Well, I'd expect `unsigned char*` for a byte array but of course the author of this struct may well have failed to follow that convention